# Moving apps to SD Card to free up space

Tags: sd-card

I recently bought an Alcatel OneTouch phone and put in a 64gb sd card, but now I have insufficient storage?? How do I get my apps to the SD CARD (there is no "Move to SD Card" option) and free up some space?

I already went to Settings -> Storage -> Default Write Disk -> SD Card but that doesn't seem to do much of anything.

Why would someone create an android phone which an SD Card did nothing?
I understand I can move pictures to it, but the apps take the most amount of space.

Thanks.

I have Android 4.4.2

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd

Download it...Enjoy moving apps to SD cards.

Note: moving apps to SD will not FULLY move the file - It simply allocates the majority of the file size to the SD card and leaves behind a trace amount (not entirely sure why) - so even if you move EVERYTHING to the SD card, you will notice that your phone memory is still lower than it would be if you have no apps..but still leaving much more than if the apps were on your phone memory :)

**edit**

For clarity...I have no association with that app or its developer(s), it's just simply the app I selected to use many moons ago and often recommend it, there may be better or sleeker options, but I am far too lazy to look when this one does the job just fine! :D

Comment: Does it do anything extra that Android does not offer? [Their FAQ states](http://android.a0soft.com/?url=App2SD.htm): *"Moving app to SD is handled by Android. App 2 SD app only provides an UI for you to manage it."*

Comment: That wording is quite vague...What that is basically saying is, that although Android does actually complete the task, App2SD actually gives you a GUI to be able to access that function.  On my phone (HTC Desire HD) I have no menu options to be able to do this without the use of an app like this :)

Comment: I actually tried this app and it says push the "Move to SD Card" button but that button does not exist, so sadly this app does not help. Thanks though.

Comment: No idea then.  It has worked for me without fail on both the HTC Desire HD and a Samsung Galaxy Europa.  Maybe you missed something, or maybe the phone simply doesn't allow it.