# Why isn't my internal storage usage going down after adopting an SD card?

Tags: external-sd, lineageos, adoptable-storage

I have an Honor 5X running LineageOS, and I'm trying to use an external SD card as adoptable storage. After migrating my data, my internal shared storage usage does not go down. Specifically, "Music & audio" shows up as 6.9 GB on both the internal shared storage and the SD card. There's also an unusual "-6.1GB" under "Other" when I look at the storage usage for the SD card.

[image: Storage summary for "SanDisk SD card"]

I don't know if it's relevant, but the "Music" directory is being watched by Syncthing. Is there something I did wrong in setting this up?

Comment: Run `df -h` on some terminal emulator app to get actual space usage. Related: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) and [How to free Internal Storage by moving data to Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526).

Answer (score 2):

The comment from Irfan Latif pointed me in the right direction. My "Music" directory was still on `/data/media/0` as well as the adopted mount. I deleted it from `/data/media/0`, the directory still shows up in `/storage/emulated/0`, and the usage summary makes sense now. Down to half usage.