# System storage taking up loads of space after adopting SD card

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, adoptable-storage

I recently adopted an SD card to my Xiaomi Redmi 7. Before I adopted the 64GB card, I was using around 8GB. Now my file manager says I am only using 2%, and under internal storage in settings I have 60GB of internal storage free. But under storage in settings, it says system storage is using 55GB and I only have 500MB free. I'm also getting the old notifications saying my storage is running out.

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure I understand the difference between internal and system storage, but I definitely can't see how system storage is using 55GB when it previously was happy with 7.

If anyone can help I would be most grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this question is about how the space is used up by apps, it is the system storage that appears to be using 55gb on my phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“System” using 342GB storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/system-using-342gb-storage)

Comment: May be your system has a "display bug" and therefore shows the sd-card as occupied because the space is used by the adopted storage partition. May be other apps like [DiscInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)  can solve this riddle.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that.

Comment: This has maybe confused me a bit more, diskinfo doesn't seem to recognise the sd card at all and says I have used 7.5gb of 8gb of data space. Which maybe is a clue to what's going on.....

Comment: I have added an image from drives. It shows the data filling up the 8gb as it did before I adopted the sd card, you can also see the almost empty as card. Perhaps I was confused, but I thought adopting the sd card would prevent this, I can't really see now what the benefit of adopting it was.

Comment: see accepted answer from Ghostkeeper (2nd link)

Comment: I have looked at that one now, the thing is, when I go to settings>storage> there is no sd card anymore since adopting, only non system storage and system storage, and cleaner, and not 3 dots in the corner, no way of going anywhere other then using the cleaner. new pic added.