# I can't transfer data to my microSD

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I'm on Android 7.1.1. I can't transfer data to my microSD, allegedly because of a lack of space which it has plenty of, actually (it used to be brimful, though).

[image].[image].[image]

<sup>Click the image to see in full size</sup>

What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: android does not allow moving apps to portable storage, therefore you get error message "not enough storage" while trying. reformat your MicroSD Card as internal [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) first

Comment: @alecxs But I successfully did it before

Comment: what you did before was moving apps to */sdcard* (which is your internal emulated storage `EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) but it is full now. adopt MicroSD Card first so that */sdcard* points to */mnt/expand/\** instead, then try again

Comment: @alecxs what do you mean by "adopt MicroSD Card"?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220729

Comment: Might also help to mention the device model, in case if the manufacturer disables the adoptable storage.

Comment: @alecxs could you write an answer with the instructions? I have hard time following you (I read the page you suggested)

Comment: only if you prefer to format from command line, enable usb-debugging in hidden developer options and download [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads). connect phone, install `android_winusb.inf` and in `cmd.exe` type *'adb.exe devices'* then confirm connection on screen (you are now ready for adb shell commands) https://jimcofer.com/2016/03/10/marshmallow-lg-and-adoptable-storage