# Phone is just pretending to move app data to external storage?

Tags: external-sd, storage, samsung-galaxy-s, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-8

My internal storage is full, so I've bought a SD-card and I'm trying to move some application data. For example I have 20GB of data for Audible which is my main concern.

I went in to Settings > Apps > Audible and there it says "Storage: 20 GB used in internal storage".

I clicked Storage > Change and selected SD Card and I got up a loader informing me of the progress of moving my data and informing me that the move is complete. Now Audible is saying that I'm using 20 GB of external data.

But Storage in Device Manager is still saying that my internal memory is full, and that I only have an insignificant amount of data, 2 GB from other things, on the SD Card. But then just under that summary, it is saying that is has 20 GB in application data in the SD Card. I'm only using 2/60GB, but at the same time it's informing me that I have 20 GB of application data on it?

This does not add up, what is happening? I've tried restarting the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214233/how-to-free-internal-storage-by-moving-data-or-using-symlink-bind-mount-with-a)

Comment: @alecxs I feel a little bit confused, how do that question relate to mine? Are you saying I have some problem with symlinks?

Comment: @Alex no you have some problem with **"moving data"** which is the first part of the linked question, symlinks come after that.

Comment: @IrfanLatif That seems like a very general problem, I don't see how that relates in a meaningful way to the problem that I have with the app saying that it's data is stored externally while no data actually seem to have been moved?

Comment: run df/du from adb shell to examine occupied space, it might happened that this app moved it's stuff to /sdcard (which might still pointing to internal storage instead of /mnt/expand)