# Formatted sd card android 6 Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card, data-recovery, adoptable-storage, formatting

I have a big problem with recovering files from a SD Card.
I had a SD Card putted as internal memory on an Infinix android 6 Marshmallow, i've accidentally formatted the sd card when inserted on my PC to copy files, i've tested all the recovery program but no luck, i've found that when the sd card is used as internal it got encrypted.
So is there any way to recover files or to decrypt the sd card ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Unfortunately, no way. When you use adoptable-storage (tag added to question) the device and SD card become one unit. Any changes to SD like you did will render device useless. You will need to format it. See the [tag wiki link](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) to learn more and decide if you really want to adopt next time

Comment: But when i removed the SD Card from the device the phone is still working and all my apps was there, but the pictures on the SD Card were inaccessible, so when i'm trying to recover files i didn't get anythings

Comment: @achrafr'b phone still worked because your SD card only contained your personal files. And you hadn't moved apps to SD card. See details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526 // Trying to recover files won't get anything because when formatted as internal/adoptable storage, SD card is encrypted. And you can't recover anything from encrypted SD card after it's formatted. See details here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526

Comment: I've used unformat and he has detected 3 partitions with index0 / 1 / 2 starting from different sectors and 2 parts are with bad status and the partt with index 0 has good status but unformat didn't recover any data
Is it an indice to recover my files or no luck because i didn't remember if i used my sd card as external or internal on the phone