# Data gone after adding a new SD card and formatting as internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, formatting

I've just added a Samsung EVO 128GB MicroSD card to a Fairphone3 and formatted it to "internal storage"

After that WhatsApp is not able to find media any more and pictures located in "DCIM" seem to be vanished.

However when I inspect the storage devices in the Android settings it looks like a lot of the space of the SD card - as well as the internal storage are in use.

Stragely Android reports the SD card to be 256GB instead of 128 - while gparted tells me the correct size.

Is there any way to find out where my data has gone?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214233

Comment: Have you tested the sd-card before using it if it is a fake (shows higher capacity that actual flash chip)?

Comment: It looks like Android just displays 130GB as 256GB - on adb shell, the correct size is being reported and I just made a `dd-rescue` of the whole sd-card without any errors. So it looks like transferring data to the 'internal storage' killed data.

Comment: WhatsApp files are still there in /data/media/0 but /sdcard is no longer targeting it. you can move files from internal storage into adoptable storage /mnt/expand which is accessable via /sdcard now. use the Migrate Data option. see linked question