# Internal Storage has no space even with SD card?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

So I have an LGK4 android phone with 8GB of storage, and lately I've been having really weird storage problems; When I try to install or update an app I can't because the storage is full; thing is, I've already cleared my cache, deleted unnecessary apps, and all my photos/videos etc are on the SD card. The apps I do have installed all come to 3.16GB, which theoretically should be the only things on the internal storage, but it still says I just have 611MB available? What happened to those 4GB? To top it all off, I can't access any files on the internal storage, it literally doesn't have any icon or button to access it, so I can't see what's causing this. Any ideas? Should I do a factory reset?

[image: Breakdown of storage space]

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: You don't consider the Android system itself which also requires storage. Typically on a 8GB device like yours half of the storage thus ~4GB are already occupied by the system itself.