# How to set SD card to default for storage S9+

Tags: storage

How do I tell my phone to store new files on my sd card instead of its internal storage, either for a specific app or the entire system?

(I did try to find this on my own. There are many sites that say how to do this. Unfortunately, none of them are accurate as the settings options have apparently changed)

Comment: You can't: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526. Use Adoptable Storage: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526

Comment: Are you sure? It was the default storage location for the photos I took until I removed and reinserted the card a few days ago. Was this feature suddenly removed or something?

Comment: Please read the answer I linked first. Apps can always save data to their private directories on external SD card (which get deleted when the app is uninstalled), but not to the rest of the directories. But saving to external storage is entirely an app's (or its developer's) personal coice. You cannot force it on any or every app.

Comment: what you looking for is in camera app settings

Comment: Thanks alecxs. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it