# Fixing bind mount on android 11 (Lineage OS)

Tags: mount, internal-sd, bind-mount

On the lineage OS 18.1 there is my internal data somewhere but the OS has problem to mount it on `sdcard` and `emulated/0` and has no access to the files. I can see my files by `ls /data/media/0` command in `adb shell`.
Is there anyway to fix it.

Comment: check */mnt/expand* is mounted */storage/emulated* maybe https://android.stackexchange.com/q/214233