# How are you supposed to use an sd card on android?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, internal-sd

I have a fairphone, and I just bought a 128GB sd card for it to expand my storage. I chose the "Use as internal storage" option. Now I want to do stuff like, download osmand maps onto it, download stuff onto it through newpipe, and, like, actually access the files on it through a file manager.

The thing is, I can't see the sdcard anywhere in the file manager. Using termux as root, I seem to be able to access it on /mnt/expand/q506de..... but nothing except root seems to be able to actually access that. Like, what am I supposed to do here? Should I have formatted it as portable storage? Do I need to, idk, create a folder on it, give it read/write permissions for the user and symbolic link it to /storage/emulated/0? Can I still put apps on it if I format as portable storage? Do I have to choose between storing files or apps on it?

Comment: Whatever files you are seeing in any file explorer app should already be on the SD card if you have done it properly: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data to Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Ok, so, "migrate data" (I really wish android was more clear about what it is actually doing) would sorta work I guess. But then what happens to my phone's filesystem? There is still 64 GB there that I also would like to be able to use. The most ideal setup for me would be to have a folder on the sd card that was just accessable, is that an option?  Is it a good idea to manually start mounting / linking stuff? Or wil that cause problems?

Comment: afaik you can control install location of apps. regarding external storage */storage/emulated* (aka */data/media*) it's all or nothing. but as your phone is rooted you can use FolderMount

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions)

Comment: I guess the awnser is that it is possible if I put in the effort to do it manually, but there isn't really a proper android way. I might just end up setting it up as portable storage to keep things simple. If it retains its mount point, I might even create some links for like DCIM if that works.