# How exactly does Android deal with adoptable storage (SD card as internal storage)?

Tags: adoptable-storage

I have a couple of confusions about this:

1. Does Android just randomly write data to its internal storage and the adopted SD card? Or does it only write to the adopted storage only when the internal storage is full?
2. What happens if the SD card gets damaged or just intentionally removed? Does the phone crash and require a factory reset?

Sorry for asking 2 questions together, but hopefully it is okay since they are related to the same subject.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. A brief description of how adoptable storage works: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526 // 2. Android reverts back to using `userdata` partition (`/data`).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks brother. But it would be really appreciated if you could post it as an answer but in a bit of layman's terms.

Comment: You might also wish to visit our [adoptable-storage tag wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info) for some background. Side note: More and more places point out that you should only use adoptable storage if you have no other choice. Some reasons for this are outlined in the linked wiki article.