# How to secure files in SD card by using adoptable storage?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, encryption, adoptable-storage

I asked [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248331/how-exactly-does-android-deal-with-adoptable-storage-sd-card-as-internal-storag) question before, and this is a follow-up.

I am trying to encrypt my SD card for data security (I don't want some random guy to be able to access my photos/documents/downloads by just plugging the SD card into another device in case my phone is lost or stolen). This is a frustrating missing feature in Android. The only way I could find to achieve this is by using SD card as internal storage.

I don't mind if SD card breaks and data is lost because I keep backups. Also I don't mind a bit slower phone as long as the data is encrypted. And also, it's fine if the SD card storage is merged with the internal storage and it acts like one single storage.

In [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) it says-

> whatever real internal storage you had will become invisible to both
> mtp and normal (non-root) file management apps, and even then, it can
> only be accessed with considerable difficulty as a mounted storage.

I don't fully understand this. Does this mean I cannot normally browse my files?

So in summary, I am trying to have an encrypted SD card and be able to browse the files and use them in different apps. Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: assuming phone comes with 64 GB total, 45 GB are reserved for app data + media and you have 23 GB free disk space - in the moment of redirecting media to external MicroSD Card via adoptable-storage, these 23 GB become unavailable to you (wasted disk space)

Comment: @alecxs Sorry for the long delay, somehow your comment missed my radar. Is it something like this example: phone storage currently: 32 GB total, 10 GB free; after adding new 64 GB SD card as adoptable: 96 (32+64) GB total, 64 GB free (this 64 GB is from the SD card, and the old 10 GB is gone)?